# 2016 MacBook Pro sometimes loose fingerprint on restart

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

I have the 15-inch 2016 MacBook Pro. About every day I have to restart my computer because of some problems. I notice that sometimes when I restart my computer all my fingerprints are gone to nowhere. I then has to put all of my Touch ID fingerprints back into my computer. This doesn't happen on every reboot, I think there is about 1/20 chance of it happening but it is still annoying. Anybody else also have this problem?

**EDIT:**

I found out that the Touch ID fingerprint only get lost during force restart (when my computer lock up and I power it down with the Touch ID button).

Comment: I noticed this for the first time after a restart this weekend, have not seen it up to now - running for approximately 1 month on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I just got off a call with Apple Tech Support.

They suggested holding the <kbd>P</kbd> key with the touch/power button the next time my Mac is frozen. That will bring up options to safe-reboot without losing fingerprints.

I'll have to wait for the next freeze event to verify this.

Comment: Did you ever verify this?